# ARIMA OLS regression with Newey West standard errors in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, neweywest

In R I am trying to run an ARIMA model

```
rsi_model_2 <- arima(dlog_seasonal_RSI_ts, order=c(0,0,1), seasonal=c(0,0,1))
```

How do I make sure it uses Newey-West standard errors? Or should it make use of them automatically?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation by doing `?arima`?

Comment: `arima` doesn't use OLS, especially not for a pure MA process...

Comment: einar, yes I have read the docs.

Chris, it uses mle to my knowledge. does one not still require newey-west standard errors despite mle estimation ? I thought you did, given the autocorrelation that exists.

Comment: The autocorrelation that exists where? In the original series? Or in the residuals? You should not have autocorrelation in your residuals.

Comment: Yes, ie if they take an AR(p) structure for example as opposed to white noise, but you don't care for modelling it correctly in your software/code, you can still obtain correct parameter estimates for alpha/beta for example, and correct t-stats by using Newey West standard errors. Or at least that's what I've learnt...

Comment: You shouldn't use HAC covariances (like Newey-West) for models that explicitly account for autocorrelation. The idea is that you either appropriately account for the autocorrelation in the model (e.g., by selecting a suitable ARIMA model) or you do not model autocorrelation at all and just adjust the inference, e.g., by means of a HAC covariance.

Comment: But that is exactly the issue - ie, the model is not 100% suitable/well-specified, ie the residuals are not white noise. Hence the requirement to model with HAC. In any case, I opted to use Gretl as it makes this very easy to do whereas in R I simply ran into endless problems.